# Create mySQL table with city attribute that can only be one of three different cities

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, create-table, workbench

I'm trying to write a script that creates a database using MySQL Workbench. I need to create a table with an attribute called "city". This attribute can only be Sydney, Brisbane or Melbourne and it needs to have a constraint that ensures it has no other value when data is inserted. How do I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse (
    warehouseNumber int NOT NULL,
    warehouseName varchar(255),
    streetNumber varchar(255),
    streetName varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    suburb varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    postcode varchar(255),
    warehouseHeadName varchar(255),
    numberEmployees int,

    PRIMARY KEY (warehouseNumber)
);
```

Comment: An ENUM could satisfy this requirement. What's the table called?

Comment: The table is called Warehouse

Comment: Um, but that doesn't have a column called cities

Comment: Oh sorry, its called "city", the create table script I posted is the one that needs to have the constraint

Comment: Great, so now you have your answer (subject to the limitations described in the manual)

Comment: And anyway, what's wrong with Newcastle?

Comment: No I have not really gotten any answer to my question, how would I create a check constraint to ensure that the data for "city" is either Sydney, Brisbane or Melbourne and not any other city? There's nothing wrong with Newcastle, the user needs to be limited to 3 city choices

Comment: Is a CHECK CONSTRAINT now a requirement of the brief? If so, create a separate cities table, with only those three values.

Comment: CHECK constraint does not work in MySQL. You can either use Enum datatype. Or, create a separate Cities table (id, City), and make City as a FK between the two tables.

Comment: Thank you Madhur, I need to use Enum datatype instead of varchar.

Comment: Um, that's what I said.

Comment: I only just realised that you mentioned that in your first comment, my mistake, thank you for the help @Strawberry